# IS OAuth secure enough, I see client secret is being past via the client side

Tags: authentication, web, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am going over this example: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-oauth-authentication-with-digitalocean-as-a-user-or-developer

After I get the code (user has authenticated on the authentication service provider), I submit another POST to that server, which this time includes the client_Secret.
https://cloud.digitalocean.com/v1/oauth/token?client_id=client_id&**client_secret=client_secret**&code=code_from_user_redirect&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=callback_URL

Shouldn't this part be hidden and done on the server side only?
Is there another layer of security I am missing here?
(This is browser based flow).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the example is for the [authorization code grant type](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2#grant-type-authorization-code), which, as you also mentioned, shouldn't be used by client applications as it would reveal the client secret.

If you're going to use a client side app (mobile app, JavaScript etc.), you should prefer the [implicit grant type](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2#grant-type-implicit). You'll directly get an access token, but the downside is that you won't have the option of a refresh token. [Here](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/oauth/#client-application-flow)'s the DigitalOcean doc for further details.

Comment: so, I should do the initial auth via server side 2 server side only, correct? If I use the Auth Code Grant type.

Comment: Yes, the authz code grant type should only be used when the authz code to token exchange is done via server to server communication. This way the client secret won't be revealed.